# Not show ids in django response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

Good day guys, I'm using rest-freamework to create some APIs, in the response I don't want to show ids in the foreign fields.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Team",
    "description": "This is my team",
    "dealership": 1,
    "users": [
        6,
        9,
    ]
}
```

In change I want something like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "My Team",
    "description": "This is my team",
    "dealership": "Chevrolet Miami",
    "users": [
        "Jack Black",
        "Brad Pitt"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please write code of your serializers file too.

Answer (score 0):

Gilbeesh, the serializer code is:

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Teams
        fields = ["id", "name", "description", "dealership", "users"]
```